# Comparing every column of one table with every column of another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables in two databases one of them is copied(through informatica mapping and i can't replace it by simple insert)from other table so I need to see if every column has the same data as the original table. If I want to test one column I do:

```
Select column1
from 
table1
minus
Select column1
from 
table2@dblink
```

If I did this on every single column of a table having 100 columns it will be a waste of time. I tried this to compare :

```
Select column1,column2,.....column N
from 
table1
minus
Select column1,column2,.....column N
from 
table2@dblink
```

But, it returned me all values even if one column was not matching. So I was wondering what is the best way to do this so that my scripts compares two tables and returns me columns which do not have identical values.

Another criteria that comes to my mind is :

```
select 
(case when T.column1 <> P.column1 then T.id else null),
...
...
...
from
table1 T,
schema.table1@dblink P
where
T.id=P.id
and T.date>='01-DEC-2012'
and T.date<='10-DEC-2012'
and P.date>='01-DEC-2012'
and P.date<='10-DEC-2012';
```

i used to date function to make the performance better.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980462/how-to-compare-two-tables-column-by-column-in-oracle) says there is a third part tool with 14 day trial version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the oracle  [except keyword](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/rdb/pdf/tech_archive/except_intersect_minus_ops.pdf)

```
Select * from tableA
except 
Select * from tableb
```

this will give you all rows that exist in a and not b

```
select * from tableb
except 
select * from tablea
```

this will give you all rows that exist in b and not a

Comment: @gh9.I don't know if except will work like that because the way you explained i tried and i am getting SQL command not properly ended error and if i just use minus the statements runs.

Comment: this link is over 10 years old, lol: "The examples in this article use SQL language from Oracle Rdb V7.1 and later versions"

Comment: @Auguster if tablea has the same schema as tableb then it will work. Do they have the same schema?

Comment: @Auguster well shame on me. It seems the minus keyword is oracle's except. The idea still should be the same. You should be able to do a select * from tableA minus select * from tableb

Comment: @gh9 Thanks so looks like what i was doing is correct but it returns complete rows and then i have to look into each single record to see which one is not matching...is there a simpler way to find which column of row didn't match i was planning on using case statement but not sure how.

Comment: @Auguster if you are down to trying to figure out which column doesnt match, i think you are better served figureing out which table is the authoritative table. Then erasing the non authoritative row and replacing it with the authoritative row. IE if tableA is the primary and it has data tableB doesnt you add it, If tableb has a bad row you replace it with tableA's row

Comment: @gh9 My work is to figure out if the columns in tableB are exact copy of tableA we use informatica to get the data into B table so to test the mapping i need to know which column is bad when we copied the data and minus gives me lot of columns.

Answer (score -1):

Don't even bother doing the test.  Truncate Table_B and insert into Table_B from Table_A.  If you don't want Table_B to change, make it READ ONLY.

Comment: I am testing the mapping by testing if one table got the data correct.So need to make a query that tests all columns got the correct value or not if not which column is getting mismatching value

Comment: How many rows in the tables?  Is this onetime?  You could extract tables to files and then md5sum the files.  If the md5sum is the same you can safely assume the tables are the same.

Comment: Submitted prior comment before done ...... How many rows in the table?  Is this onetime?  Do you think the mapping is correct and you just need to prove it or do you know there are mapping errors and you need to find them?  To prove the table match, you could extract/spool tables to files and then md5sum the files.  If the md5sum is the same you can safely assume the tables are the same.

Comment: I need to find if any mismatch and prove it too and the table has some 150 or more columns and rows will go in millions for even a 5 days so extracting is not a good approach here and i need to find what causes the mismatch so its not easier for me to export find the mismatch and then go back to database to find what causes the mismatch,what i was trying is to make one generic query that tests the whole table for some limited time period.

Comment: I am not aware of any Oracle "magic" that is going to go this for you - you will need to write the code.  First identify the mismatched rows and then compare the columns.