# Oracle - Compare rows with large number of columns

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I need to compare 2 rows with large number of columns.

It is something like

```
ID A  Column1 Column2 .....
ID B  Column1 Column2 .....
ID C  Column1 Column2 .....
```

I need to compare large amounts of columns like doing subtraction on them.
I do not want a minus from tables, I want to put similar operation on all the columns.
Any one call tell me how to do this without referring every column with name.
Operation like subtraction or addition remains same on every column.

Basically understand it like this.

```
CDE01 A 06 C D
PDE02 B 07 C D
PDE03 A 05 C D
```

Therefore if I compare with CDE01 the other rows have 2 and 3 columns same.
I have a table with many columns like that who need to be matched.
The table will have two such kind of rows and I need to compare every row of one set based on a where clause with every row of others subset. Like PDE and CDE are two different kind of rows here.

Comment: Examples of needed output ?

Comment: how would you specify the operations on columns without referring to the columns by name ? you could query the data dictionary to determine the columns' names given their position but this would be rather error-prone to say the least.

Comment: "...compare large amounts of columns like doing subtraction on them..." doesn't explain what you're trying to accomplish.  Please edit your post and provide additional details.

Comment: Not clear and understandable. Please edit and add more details about what exactly you intend to do, what are your resources, what are your table and column names (not exactly the real names, but example that are illustrative enough) and what you have tried so far..

Comment: I have updated it, See if you guys can get this !

Comment: "CDE01 A 06 C D PDE02 B 07 C D PDE03 A 05 C D"  This is unreadable.  Is this multiple rows?  Please provide a COMPLETE exampe.  Don't expect people can read your mind.  If you don't put in the effort to fomulate a thoughtful question, don't expect and good responses.

Comment: @LeorA - it was a minor formatting issue - no spaces before the `CDE01 A 06 etc...`.  @darksun - you can find info on how to mark up your posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Share and enjoy.

Comment: OK, now we can see your data, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do.  If we take the column names as ID, COL1, COl2, COL3, COL4, and COL5, would it be correct to say you're trying to do something like `SELECT * FROM A_TABLE a1 INNER JOIN A_TABLE a2 WHERE a1.ID <> a2.ID AND (a1.COL1 = a2.COL1 OR a1.COL2 = a2.COL2 OR a1.COL3 = a2.COL3 OR a1.COL4 = a2.COL4 OR a1.COL5 = a2.COL5)`, but you don't want to name all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create two views (or more as needed).  Each view represents what you consider to be a grouping (you refer to them as kinds of rows).  So you might end up with a view: CDE_data and PDE_data.

You then have to determine what it mean for the rows to be different.  From the data you provided, I don't see any matches at all - you need to determine how one row from CDE_data would match a PDE_data row.   It may be that you are matching only on that second column (A and B).  If that's the case, then join cde_dta to pde_data based on that and then use the solution here:

[How to compare two tables column by column in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980462/how-to-compare-two-tables-column-by-column-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the metadata to generate the comparison. I thought I just answered a question like this...

Answer (score -1):

To compare huge amount of data in tables, you can use "**Oracle GoldenGate Veridata**" or heaps of third party tools like any of the following:

Toadsoft.com/ -- Shareware

dkgas.com/oradbdiff.htm

softtreetech.com/dbtools/

impacttoys.com/supported_ora_features.htm -- Free

Comment: Seriously is this advertisement on stack overflow ? You did not even try to understand my question.

Comment: @dark-read your question and try to understand it yourself. Impossible! TOAD has compare data features etc... From menu select Database->Compare then select option.